# Remove Selected Item from Array in jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I have this array,

```
var metrics = [
        {
            value: "1",
            label: "Sold Listings",
            desc: "sold_listings"
        },
        {
            value: "10",
            label: "New Pendings",
            desc: "new_pendings"
        },
        {
            value: "4",
            label: "All Pendings",
            desc: "all_pendings"
        },
        {
            value: "2",
            label: "New Listings",
            desc: "new_listings"
        },
        {
            value: "3",
            label: "Active Listings",
            desc: "active_listings"
        }
    ];
```

What I wanted to do is to the Selected item, for example I will select Active Listings, this item should be deleted from the array. So that when  the autocomplete renders again, it won't show the selected item.

```
//My Idea of removing the item
            $.each(metrics,function(i,val){
                if(val.value == ui.item.value){
                    delete metrics[i];
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't update the source of `autocomplete`.
To do it you have to use the following line.

`$('.yourAutocomplete').autocomplete('option', 'source', yourArray);`

So, on autocomplete select event:

Assuming that `#autocomplete` is your `input`.

```
select: function(e, ui) {
    metrics = jQuery.grep(metrics, function(element) {
        return element.value != ui.item.value;
    });
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete('option', 'source', metrics)
    return false;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex3Rp/)

*Reference*:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-option

Comment: how about if you add back the selected item into the array, when the remove button is clicked?

Comment: @Jetoox Remove one and add other ?

Comment: no. example if i click the removed button on one of the added items, how do i push it back into the array?

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-add-and-remove-array-value-in-jquery) post, you can do something like:

```
var y = [1, 2, 3] 
var removeItem = 2; 

y = jQuery.grep(y, function(value) { 
  return value != removeItem; 
});
```

EDIT:

For your example, you could do:

```
var removeItem = "1"; 
metrics = $.grep(metrics, function(val) { 
    if (val.value != removeItem) {
        return val;
    }
});
```

This will remove the first array item with value "1" property.

Comment: what if the array format is the same as I posted? Would that still be applicable with what you have answered?